# What is pack size ?

Tags: c#, .net, unmanaged

I was reading about unmanaged code in C#, and came across the following line:-

> In a C# program CLR finds the offset using field tokens.
>   C field names are directly compiled into offsets. For access speed each field is placed at an offset that is a multiple of field's size.
>   That multiplier is however restricted to a maximum of x bytes, where x is the "pack size".

My question is that what is Pack Size ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computer architecture it's a lot faster to have things be [byte aligned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).  When language specs talk about pack size, this is a matter of saying that the compiler will automatically create larger slots for data sizes depending on how things align.  This means that sometimes what you think will be a 2 byte field, can actually be at a 4 byte slot in memory.  If you want to shave off storage size, in exchange for cpu slowdown, you can adjust the pack size.

Check the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx) on pack for more info.

To quote this [tutorial](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/):

> Historically memory is byte addressable and arranged sequentially. **If
>   the memory is arranged as single bank of one byte width, the processor
>   needs to issue 4 memory read cycles to fetch an integer. It is more
>   economical to read all 4 bytes of integer in one memory cycle.** To take
>   such advantage, the memory will be arranged as group of 4 banks as
>   shown in the above figure.
>
> The memory addressing still be sequential. If bank 0 occupies an
>   address X, bank 1, bank 2 and bank 3 will be at (X + 1), (X + 2) and
>   (X + 3) addresses. If an integer of 4 bytes is allocated on X address
>   (X is multiple of 4), the processor needs only one memory cycle to
>   read entire integer.
>
> Where as, **if the integer is allocated at an address other than
>   multiple of 4, it spans across two rows of the banks as shown in the
>   below figure. Such an integer requires two memory read cycle to fetch
>   the data.**
>
> ...
>
> A variable’s data alignment deals with the way the data stored in
>   these banks. For example, the natural alignment of int on 32-bit
>   machine is 4 bytes. When a data type is naturally aligned, the CPU
>   fetches it in minimum read cycles.
>
> Similarly, the natural alignment of short int is 2 bytes. It means, a
>   short int can be stored in bank 0 – bank 1 pair or bank 2 – bank 3
>   pair. A double requires 8 bytes, and occupies two rows in the memory
>   banks. Any misalignment of double will force more than two read cycles
>   to fetch double data.
>
> Note that a double variable will be allocated on 8 byte boundary on 32
>   bit machine and requires two memory read cycles. On a 64 bit machine,
>   based on number of banks, double variable will be allocated on 8 byte
>   boundary and requires only one memory read cycle.

While the languages are different, the concept is the same

Answer (score 4):

I'll take the details of field alignment as a given, covered in devshorts' quote.  The pack size setting is where the compiler stops trying to keep a field aligned because it is too big.

It is a compiler setting or a #pragma in native code.  A tricky one on Intel processors because they are flexible and allow misaligned data with little to no penalty.  A pack size of 8 is a very common default and almost always correct.  Sometimes it is 1 or 4.  The Pack property in your [StructLayout] declaration must match, if it doesn't then you'll have good odds for reading garbage because you'll read a field at the wrong memory location.